# php - creating a function, to use later in same page

Tags: php, function

I am trying to add a function named "addNotification" to my page "functions.php"

My function:

```
function addNoti($text,$userid)
{
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO notifications (time,text,userid) VALUES('".time()."','$text','$userid')");
    if(mysql_affected_rows() != 1)
        return 2;
    else
        return 100;
}
```

A couple of hundreds line BELOW that^ (same page), I have my registration function "register":

```
    function doRegister()
    {

        global $datesetting;
mysql_query("query to register goes here");
addNoti("You just joined us!","$userid");

}
```

Although, whenever I process my registration form, I get the following error:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function addNoti() in /home/domain/public_html/path/to/functions.php on line 278
```

(Line 278 is where the addNoti is called)

Whenever I try to move addNoti to another page, and load that page in functions.php I get no error.

Please help.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I'm sure you know this, but just in case, you know that you are passing, literally, the string "$userid" and NOT what that represents, right? (for your script, that should actually be empty).

Comment: $userid is declared in my script.

Comment: if it's declared in that same function or declared as a global (as it should be to have some value inside the function), you should write this: `addNoti("You just joined us!",$userid);`

Comment: Search all your sources for "addNoti"...

Comment: After reading all the answers I am very much curious to know where exactly the problem is :-)

Comment: If your source is exactly like you have posted here, it should work. This is all correct. Check for errors, brackets, spelling-errors etc.

Comment: If all the function names are correct, and `addNoti()` is defined before `doRegister()`, I'd be inclined to believe it's a scope-related issue :p

Comment: The spelling and the names are correct. It is addNoti() and not addNotification (sorry about that one).
I am not getting any error about any unclosed brackets or anything else.

Comment: Not necessarily errors, read topp's answer, my best guess would be that the function is defined outside of the scope of where it's trying to be accessed. Make sure your `addNoti()` function is not nested inside of any conditional statements/other functions etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep in mind that in PHP you can declare function in conditional block. It could be that in your code execution took the other branch and never got to the function definition. Check the code blocks, check if the code with the function definition gets executed (`echo` or `var_dump` are your friends)

Answer (score 1):

Is it a typo? In your question you name the function `addNotification` and `addNoti()`...

Answer (score 0):

Do you call doRegister() before addNoti() occurred in your script?! That is the question!

Comment: As said in my question: "A couple of hundreds line BELOW that^ (same page), I have my registration function "register":" - therefore, I first declare the addNoti function, and THEN call the doRegister()

Comment: Also, if he calls the function doRegister(), before ocurring both, it should give the error for this function, and not for the addNoti..

Answer (score 0):

From the two functions only it is hard to say what the problem can be. Did you accidently put the function addNoti inside another function (before the closing bracket)?